# SQL Server Rows to Columns Dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

Below are my table and query details.

### Table definition

```
create table #ReviewData
    (
    ProjectId int,
    ReviewId int,
    ReviewDataPointKey varchar(max),
    ReviewDataPointValue varchar(max)
    )
```

### Data in table

```
Insert into #ReviewData values 
  (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_FacilityTypeId', 'Hospital_Inpatient')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_FacilityTypeId', 'Hospital_Inpatient_Other')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F11.14', 'F11.14_text')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F11.15', 'F11.15_text')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F12.16', 'F12.16_text')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F12.17', 'F12.17_text')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterStartDate', '11/04/2019')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterEndDate', '11/04/2019')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterStartDate', '11/08/2019')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterEndDate', '11/08/2019')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisPageNumber', '3')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisPageNumber', '5')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_1_ProviderCredential', 'Sample')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_2_ProviderCredential', 'Testing')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_3_DiagnosisCode_F12.16', 'F12.16_text')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_3_DiagnosisCode_F12.17', 'F12.17_text')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_3_FacilityTypeId', 'OutPatient')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_4_FacilityTypeId', 'OutPatient_Other')
, (1,73,'SaasEncounter_4_ProviderCredential', 'New')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_FacilityTypeId', 'Physician_InPatient')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_FacilityTypeId', 'Physician_InPatient_Other')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F10.14', 'F10.14_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F10.15', 'F10.15_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F20.16', 'F20.16_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F20.17', 'F20.17_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F25.14', 'F25.14_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_DiagnosisCode_F35.15', 'F35.15_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F45.16', 'F45.16_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_DiagnosisCode_F65.17', 'F65.17_text')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterStartDate', '11/04/2019')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterEndDate', '11/04/2019')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterStartDate', '11/08/2019')
, (1,901,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterEndDate', '11/08/2019')
, (1,902,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterStartDate', '11/08/2019')
, (1,902,'SaasEncounter_1_EncounterEndDate', '11/11/2019')
, (1,902,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterStartDate', '11/05/2019')
, (1,902,'SaasEncounter_2_EncounterEndDate', '11/08/2019')
```

### Simple SELECT to verify data

```
Select * from #ReviewData where ProjectId = 1
```

### SELECT statement I am trying to implement

```
select
    rd.ProjectId, 
    rd.ReviewId, 
    rdpv.ReviewDataPointValue as FacilityType,
    rdpv3.ReviewDataPointValue as DiagnosisCode,
    rdpv1.ReviewDataPointValue as EncounterStartDate,
    rdpv2.ReviewDataPointValue as EncounterEndDate,
    rdpv4.ReviewDataPointValue as DiagnosisPageNumber,
    rdpv5.ReviewDataPointValue as ProviderCredential
from
    #ReviewData rd JOIN Project P ON P.ProjectId = 1 and rd.ProjectId = 1
    JOIN Client C ON C.ClietId = P.ClientId 
outer apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%FacilityTypeId%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_FacilityTypeId', '%')

            ) rdpv
            outer apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%EncounterStartDate%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_EncounterStartDate', '%')

            ) rdpv1
                        outer apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%EncounterEndDate%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_EncounterEndDate', '%')

            ) rdpv2
                                    outer apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd2.ReviewDataPointKey like '%DiagnosisCode%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd2.ReviewDataPointKey, '_DiagnosisCode', '%')

            ) rdpv3
                                                outer apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd3
     where  rd3.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd3.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd3.ReviewDataPointKey like '%DiagnosisPageNumber%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd3.ReviewDataPointKey, '_DiagnosisPageNumber', '%')

            ) rdpv4
                                                outer apply
    (select ReviewDataPointValue
     from   #ReviewData rd4
     where  rd4.ProjectId = rd.ProjectId
            and rd4.ReviewId = rd.ReviewId
            and rd4.ReviewDataPointKey like '%ProviderCredential%'
            and rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd4.ReviewDataPointKey, '_ProviderCredential', '%')

            ) rdpv5

where
    rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%FacilityTypeId%'and
        rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%EncounterStartDate%' and
         rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%EncounterEndDate%' and 
                 rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%ProviderCredential%' and 
                         rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%ProviderCredential%' and 

         rd.ProjectId = 1
```

### My Current Output

[image]

### My Expected Output

[image]

Hi McNets,

Can you help me to get the above expected output?

Also Can you explain below two lines which you used?

1. `rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd4.ReviewDataPointKey, '_FacilityTypeId', '%')`
2. `where
   rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%FacilityTypeId%'`

Comment: Hi McNet, Whichever contains FacilityTypeId in ReviewDataPointKey column needs to be changed to FacilityType Column. Whichever contains DiagnosisCode in ReviewDataPointKey Column needs to be changed to Diagnosis Code Column

Comment: @McNets, Thank you so much. Perfect. Its working for multiple columns. I have 12 to 15 columns like this. So every time we needed to use cross apply. Is there any other better approach? Could you please suggest? Will it create any performance issue?

Comment: sure.I will do it

Comment: Hi Mcnet added new data and expected output. Can you please take a look and let me know?

Comment: Is there any `SaasEncounter_1X`?, I mean more than one numeric digit after SaasEncounter_

Comment: Hi McNet, No. After SaasEncounter_ only one numeric digit will be there. Like SaasEnCounter_1, SaasEncounter_2. But it is dynamic. Meaning SaasEncounter_1 can be available in all reviewids (Like ReviewId - 73,901,902). Also SaasEncounter_1,SaasEncounter_2...SaasEncounter_9. and so on. No limit for this. It may keep go.  Now I added new data and my output. Please take a look and let me know asap. Since I have demo tomorrow.  Share if any other approach also

Comment: Also Can you explain below two lines which you used?

rd.ReviewDataPointKey like replace(rd4.ReviewDataPointKey, '_FacilityTypeId', '%')

where rd.ReviewDataPointKey not like '%FacilityTypeId%'

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? I did not get you. FacilityTypeId why used in Where Condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you want to use all these APPLY joins, simply change all CROSS APPLY by OUTER APPLY an it will work fine.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de963666060440f3e1cec16d36417ad6)*

First and foremost let me suggest you when you ask a new question, instead of say "this is my desired result", try to describe what are you trying to achieve, in this case you need to pivot the results by Facility and DiagnosisResult.

IMHO, you're dealing with a bad design. Maybe transforming your data could improve your query.

```
create table #rd 
( 
     ProjectId int, 
     ReviewId int,
     Key1 varchar(100),
     Key2 varchar(100),
     RDPValue varchar(max),
);

create nonclustered index ix_rd on #rd
(
    ProjectId, ReviewId, Key1, Key2
)

insert into #rd
select
    ProjectId,
    ReviewId,
    substring(ReviewDataPointKey, 0, charindex('_', ReviewDataPointKey, 15)) [Key1],
    case
      when substring(ReviewDataPointKey, 
                     charindex('_', ReviewDataPointKey, 15) + 1,
                     len(ReviewDataPointKey) - charindex('_', ReviewDataPointKey, 15) + 1)
                     like 'DiagnosisCode%' then 'DiagnosisCode'
      else substring(ReviewDataPointKey, 
                     charindex('_', ReviewDataPointKey, 15) + 1,
                     len(ReviewDataPointKey) - charindex('_', ReviewDataPointKey, 15) + 1)
      end as [Key2],
    ReviewDataPointValue
from
    ReviewData
where
    ProjectId = 1;
```

I've used a temporary table to convert your original data into this:

> ```
> ProjectId | ReviewId | Key1            | Key2                | RDPValue                 
> --------: | -------: | :-------------- | :------------------ | :------------------------
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | FacilityTypeId      | Hospital_Inpatient       
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | FacilityTypeId      | Hospital_Inpatient_Other 
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisCode       | F11.14_text              
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisCode       | F11.15_text              
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisCode       | F12.16_text              
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisCode       | F12.17_text              
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | EncounterStartDate  | 11/04/2019               
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | EncounterEndDate    | 11/04/2019               
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | EncounterStartDate  | 12/08/2019               
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | EncounterEndDate    | 13/08/2019               
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisPageNumber | 3                        
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisPageNumber | 5                        
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_1 | ProviderCredential  | Sample                   
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_2 | ProviderCredential  | Testing                  
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_3 | DiagnosisCode       | F12.16_text              
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_3 | DiagnosisCode       | F12.17_text              
>         1 |       73 | SaasEncounter_3 | FacilityTypeId      | OutPatient               
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | FacilityTypeId      | Physician_InPatient      
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | FacilityTypeId      | Physician_InPatient_Other
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisCode       | F10.14_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisCode       | F10.15_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisCode       | F20.16_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisCode       | F20.17_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisCode       | F25.14_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | DiagnosisCode       | F35.15_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisCode       | F45.16_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | DiagnosisCode       | F65.17_text              
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | EncounterStartDate  | 11/04/2019               
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_1 | EncounterEndDate    | 11/04/2019               
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | EncounterStartDate  | 12/08/2019               
>         1 |      901 | SaasEncounter_2 | EncounterEndDate    | 13/08/2019
> ```

Now you can pivot your data in this way:

```
select
    rd1.ProjectId,
    rd1.ReviewId,
    rd1.RDPValue as FacilityType,
    rd2.DiagnosisCode,
    (select RDPValue
     from   #rd 
     where  #rd.ProjectId = rd1.ProjectId
            and #rd.ReviewId = rd1.ReviewId
            and #rd.Key1 = rd1.Key1
            and #rd.Key2 = 'EncounterStartDate') as EncounterStartDate,
    (select RDPValue
     from   #rd 
     where  #rd.ProjectId = rd1.ProjectId
            and #rd.ReviewId = rd1.ReviewId
            and #rd.Key1 = rd1.Key1
            and #rd.Key2 = 'EncounterEndDate') as EncounterEndDate,
    (select RDPValue
     from   #rd 
     where  #rd.ProjectId = rd1.ProjectId
            and #rd.ReviewId = rd1.ReviewId
            and #rd.Key1 = rd1.Key1
            and #rd.Key2 = 'DiagnosisPageNumber') as DiagPageNum,
    (select RDPValue
     from   #rd 
     where  #rd.ProjectId = rd1.ProjectId
            and #rd.ReviewId = rd1.ReviewId
            and #rd.Key1 = rd1.Key1
            and #rd.Key2 = 'ProviderCredential') as ProviderCredential
from
    #rd rd1
outer apply
    (select RDPValue as DiagnosisCode
     from   #rd rd2
     where  rd2.ProjectId = rd1.ProjectId
            and rd2.ReviewId = rd1.ReviewId
            and rd2.Key1 = rd1.Key1
            and rd2.Key2 = 'DiagnosisCode') rd2
where
    rd1.Key2 = 'FacilityTypeId';
```

This is the result:

> ```
> ProjectId | ReviewId | FacilityType              | DiagnosisCode | EncounterStartDate | EncounterEndDate | DiagPageNum | ProviderCredential
> --------: | -------: | :------------------------ | :------------ | :----------------- | :--------------- | :---------- | :-----------------
>         1 |       73 | Hospital_Inpatient        | F11.14_text   | 11/04/2019         | 11/04/2019       | 3           | Sample            
>         1 |       73 | Hospital_Inpatient        | F11.15_text   | 11/04/2019         | 11/04/2019       | 3           | Sample            
>         1 |       73 | Hospital_Inpatient_Other  | F12.16_text   | 12/08/2019         | 13/08/2019       | 5           | Testing           
>         1 |       73 | Hospital_Inpatient_Other  | F12.17_text   | 12/08/2019         | 13/08/2019       | 5           | Testing           
>         1 |       73 | OutPatient                | F12.16_text   | null               | null             | null        | null              
>         1 |       73 | OutPatient                | F12.17_text   | null               | null             | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient       | F10.14_text   | 11/04/2019         | 11/04/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient       | F10.15_text   | 11/04/2019         | 11/04/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient       | F25.14_text   | 11/04/2019         | 11/04/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient       | F35.15_text   | 11/04/2019         | 11/04/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient_Other | F20.16_text   | 12/08/2019         | 13/08/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient_Other | F20.17_text   | 12/08/2019         | 13/08/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient_Other | F45.16_text   | 12/08/2019         | 13/08/2019       | null        | null              
>         1 |      901 | Physician_InPatient_Other | F65.17_text   | 12/08/2019         | 13/08/2019       | null        | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0a55f6ffef506910ad3ddb650937c85)*